# Puzzling problem with latest Groovy stable release

Tags: testing, gradle, groovy, mocking

I just started a new Gradle project.  In my previous build.gradles I had been putting this:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
```

... and also these dependencies:

```
testCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.6.11'
testCompile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6'
```

By a process of trial and error I had found that Groovy 2.4.15 with these Bytebuddy and Objensis dependencies enabled me to mock `BufferedReader`.  This proved useful in a console application where I wanted to mock user input to the console. The "console handler" class thus has the following field/property:

```
def br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in, 'UTF-8' ))
```

used as follows in the app class to get user console input:

```
String response = br.readLine().trim()
```

... meaning that Spock tests can do this sort of thing:

```
def 'prompt should show help on entering H'()  {
    given:
    consoleHandler.br = Mock( BufferedReader )
    consoleHandler.br.readLine() >> 'h'
```

i.e. simulate the entry of the letter h at the console.

... but it doesn't work with Groovy 2.5.3 and its matching Spock dependency: for this new project I put:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.3'
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.5'
```

... with the same ByteBuddy and Objenisis dependencies. I get the following test failure:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type     at
>   net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)  at
>   net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
>     at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)     at
>   net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.createMock(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:42)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.createInternal(JavaMockFactory.java:58)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:38)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:42)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:46)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:294)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:284)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:100)
>     at core.FirstSpec.setup(first_tests.groovy:20)
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.isAvailable()Z
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.determineBestClassLoadingStrategy(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.access$300(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:27)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:54)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:43)
>     at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)

Any Groovy über-geeks out there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to upgrade `byte-buddy`:

```
testCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.21'
```

Spock version `1.1-groovy-2.4` was depending on `byte-buddy:1.6.5` - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core/1.1-groovy-2.4

Spock version `1.2-groovy-2.5` depends on `byte-buddy:1.8.21` - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core/1.2-groovy-2.5

Comment: Wonderful, thanks.  Still a bit puzzling: if byte-buddy is a "dependency" of Spock, why doesn't Spock download it automatically when you deploy and use a given version of Spock?

Comment: This dependency is marked as optional, which means it does not get involved in dependency version resolution. When you define `1.6.5` directly in your build.gradle this is the version that gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.